# Cast Object to Double[]

Tags: java, casting

I have a method which takes a parameter of type Object.

```
protected Object foo(Object data) {
    Double[] values = (Double[]) data;    //Line-A
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(values[0] - values[3], 2)
            + Math.pow(values[1] - values[4], 2)
            + Math.pow(values[2] - values[5], 2));
}
```

At the runtime, this function throws an exception, at Line-A:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Double;
```

How can I get this function to work?

### Edit [Tuesday, April 1, 2014]

Can we please assume the following?

1. The API is totally out of my control.
2. The parameter coming in to this function (`data`) is of type `Object[]`, and I cannot change its type.

Given these assumptions, how can I get this function to work?

Comment: casting (of objects) in Java is not like casting in C. Cast succeeds only when the object is actually of the needed type (or its subtype)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cast `Object[]` to `Double[]` knowing that each your `Object` in your array is actually a `Double`, use `Arrays.copyOf` method. Otherwise it's impossible to do a "direct" cast, you must check your items type and figure out how to extract a `double` value for that.
Maybe more optimal will be using `Arrays.asList` method and cast it to `List<Double>` directly. (because `Arrays.asList` doesn't copy the array)

Example:

```
static void test(Object[] a) {
    Double[] dummy = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length, Double[].class);
    System.out.println(dummy[0]); // prints 42.0
}

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Object[] a = new Object[1];
    a[0] = new Double(42.0);
    test(a);
}
```

Example with generic List casting:

```
static void test(Object[] a) {
    List<Double> dummy = (List<Double>)((List<?>)(Arrays.asList(a)));
    System.out.println(dummy.get(0));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> I have a method which takes a parameter of type Object

Why? This is poor API design. If you expect a `Double[],` specify a `Double[].`

> At the runtime, this function throws an exception, at Line-A:

Because the argument you passed wasn't a `Double[].`

> How can I get this function to work?

Pass a `Double[]` to it as the argument.

Comment: Thanks EJP, but I cannot pass a `Double[]` as the argument. Could you please check the edit I've done to the question?

Comment: 1. Change the method parameter to Double[]. That will force whoever is being intransigent to change their code. 2. Cast each *element* of the array to Double as you process it.

Comment: Thanks EJP. "2. Cast each element of the array to Double as you process it." works.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `Object` parameter ?? You are expecting `Double[]` so use `Double[].` Having object is useful when you really don't know what is coming out (generic type perhaps?), and for a more complex design anyway. Using `Object` in this case is pointless and bad API design

So just do this

```
protected Double foo(Double[] data) {
    Double[] values = data;    //Line-A
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(values[0] - values[3], 2)
            + Math.pow(values[1] - values[4], 2)
            + Math.pow(values[2] - values[5], 2));
}
```

Comment: He is expecting `Double[],` not `Double.` It is impossible to cast `Double` to `Double[].` Your code doesn't even compile. -1

Comment: Not entirely, so I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.

```
protected Object foo(Object data) {
    Double[] values = new Double[6];  
    Object[] objectArr = (Object[]) data;
    int index = 0;
    for (Object object : objectArr) {
        values[index] = (Double)object;
        index++;
    }
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(values[0] - values[3], 2)
            + Math.pow(values[1] - values[4], 2)
            + Math.pow(values[2] - values[5], 2));
}
```

Please provide an answer if you have a better way to do this, or leave a comment if you have any concerns!

Comment: you have just reinvented a wheel. there's standard method that does the array copy and it's called... `Arrays.copyOf`

Comment: As @SargeBorsch has suggested, the for-loop can be replaced by `Double[] values = Arrays.copyOf(objectArr, objectArr.length, Double[].class);`